# How big is a Tomcat context in memory? (or is this question even relevant?)

Tags: tomcat, heap-memory

(my understanding of tomcat and context is still limited...)

I have a Tomcat application server with many web applications (all similar, 200+).

Each one of them has a Tomcat context, I wonder if each context use space in Tomcat memory and how to understand how much memory N similar web applications will need...

Can I even measure the context size in memory?

Comment: Without knowing where you want to go, did you hear about JMAP and OQL ?

Comment: I used sometimes VisualVM to profile the java machine but I hoped I could get something from java code itself

Comment: @EugèneAdell I tried jmap  -histo:live ...don't know how to get some useful insight though about context